# Excel formulas for autofil

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to autofill a cell based on a date selected in a column. Ideally I would like the date selected in the start column to be presented as a filled cell within the correlating column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly from your post, you are trying to use `Conditional Formatting` in `Excel` based on `Start Date` and it will highlight the **correlating columns**.

To achieve the above, follow the steps:

- Select the range from `B5:J8` (Range shown in example, this may change as per your suit, ensure to make the changes.)
- From `Home` Tab under `Styles` Group click on `Conditional Formatting`
- On clicking the above opens the list, click `New`
- `New Formatting Rule` window opens, and select the last rule that states, `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- Enter the formula in edit the rule description.

---

```
=($A5>=B$3)*($A5<=B$3+6)
```

---

- Click on `Format` from `Fill` Tab choose preferred color.

---

- Click `Ok` Twice.

This will do what is requested. Refer below for demonstration.

---

[image]